# Inherit event handlers

Tags: c#, .net, events, inheritance

Im trying to write abstract class for different reports.

I have a method

```
protected Tuple<byte[], string, string> RenderReport()
```

which has such lines

```
var localReport = new LocalReport { ReportPath = _reportLocalFullName };
...
localReport.SubreportProcessing += localReport_SubreportProcessing;
```

Derived class must write own code in the localReport_SubreportProcessing.

I'm not sure how to make inheritance here. Can someone help ?

Answer (score 5):

Rather than having a method:

```
private void localReport_SubreportProcessing(...) {...}
```

consider instead:

```
protected virtual void OnSubreportProcessing(...) {...}
```

Now your subclasses can simply use:

```
protected override void OnSubreportProcessing(...) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call a common method, which you override in your `base` class.

So in `localReport_SubreportProcessing`, call `ProcessSubreport`

```
private void localReport_SubreportProcessing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ProcessSubreport();
}

protected virtual void ProcessSubreport()
{ }
```

And override it in your deriving class:

```
protected override void ProcessSubreport()
{ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below.

```
public abstract class BaseReport
{
  ......
  protected Tuple<byte[], string, string> RenderReport()
  {
    var localReport = new LocalReport { ReportPath = _reportLocalFullName };
    ...
    localReport.SubreportProcessing += localReport_SubreportProcessing;
    ...
  }

  protected abstract void LocalReport_SubreportProcessing(object sender, EventArgs e);
}

public class DerivedReport1 : BaseReport
{
  protected override void LocalReport_SubreportProcessing(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // Report generation logic for report1.
  }
}

public class DerivedReport2 : BaseReport
{
  protected override void LocalReport_SubreportProcessing(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // Report generation logic for report2.
  }
}
```